# CAST BYTES to STRING in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I created the following script in Google Big Query:

SELECT CAST(user_ID AS STRING) FROM `table`

I recevied the error message: Invalid cast of bytes to UTF8 string

How can I overpass this and and join the user_id with a another one which is string?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [TO_BASE64](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#to_base64) or [TO_HEX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_hex)

Comment: Unfortunately the result is Row f0_ 
1 
null
2 
null
3 
null

Comment: Maybe TO_BASE64 or TO_HEX?